# MySQL Transaction Auto-Settler Calculation Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a little auto-settler web app for people who share bills with each other.

Quick example, if Sam, Bill and Jim all live together and share common bills such as the Electricity Bill, Gas Bill and the Broadband Charge they should be able to input each transaction to the web app and then the app auto-calculates who should pay what to whom.

There are two tables concerned with this problem: 'transactions' and 'transactionusers'.

**Transactions:** ID, UserID, Retailer, Item, Date

**Transactionusers:** ID, TransactionID, Amount, UserID

When Sam adds a 'transaction' record for the Electricity Bill ($90) and splits the amount evenly across housemates, 3 records are added to the 'transactionusers' table.

I want to be able to write an SQL Query to work out the sum of all transactions between all users and then take away the reverse transactions (EG If Sam owes Bill $50 and Bill owes Sam $20, then the settlement is that Bill owes Sam $30)

My current query allows you to sum up total transaction value between each pair of users but not take away the reverse transaction - any help much appreciated:

```
SELECT transactionusers.userID AS debtor, SUM(amount) AS owes, transactions.userID AS toUser FROM transactionusers
INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.ID = transactionusers.transactionID
WHERE transactions.userID <> transactionusers.userID
GROUP BY transactionusers.userID, transactions.userID
```

**Example Data**

Assume UserIDs are Sam (1), Bill (2), Jim (3)

**Transactions:**

`1, 1, 'Electricity Co', 'Electricity Bill'`
`2, 2, 'Gas Co', 'Gas Bill'`
`3, 3, 'Broadband Co', 'Broadband Charge'`

**Transactionusers:**

`1, 1, 30, 1`
`2, 1, 30, 2`
`3, 1, 30, 3`

`4, 2, 20, 1`
`5, 2, 20, 2`
`6, 2, 20, 3`

`7, 3, 5, 1`
`8, 3, 5, 2`
`9, 3, 5, 3`

What's not shown in the example records is the ability to split a bill unequally across users; for example: if Jim had been living in the house a month longer he may pick up a higher part of the bill

Comment: Can you show the data for your little example with Sam and Bill.  I do not see how this would be represented in your table structure.

Comment: Sure - have updated main question

Answer (score 0):

Your query is good, you simply need to do a join on the very same query and deduct the results:

```
SELECT transactionusers.userID AS debtor, IF(SUM(amount)-r.owes < 0, 0, SUM(amount)-r.owes) AS owes, transactions.userID AS toUser FROM transactionusers
INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.ID = transactionusers.transactionID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT transactionusers.userID AS debtor, SUM(amount) AS owes, transactions.userID AS toUser FROM transactionusers
    INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.ID = transactionusers.transactionID
    WHERE transactions.userID <> transactionusers.userID
    GROUP BY transactionusers.userID, transactions.userID
) r ON r.debtor = transactions.userID AND r.toUser = transactionusers.userID
WHERE transactions.userID <> transactionusers.userID
GROUP BY transactionusers.userID, transactions.userID
```